# Python Tkinter: Run python script when click button_widget of tkinter and keep value from return variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new with GUI programming in Python 3.x with Tkinter.

I have prepared a GUI where user needs to select options (using OptionMenu widget) and after selection press button to run the final program.

I have saved the user selected data into variables in that GUI program.

But don't know what should I do next...

What I want:

- That GUI should be hidden or End after pressing the button.
- Run another python script and use those saved variables from that GUI in my script.

How it can be done in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your data in another file in order to use it in other script with pickle module.

To save you can do a list with all the variables you want:

```
import pickle

with open('doc_name.txt','wb') as a:
     pickle.dump(saved_variable_list,a)
```

And in another python script you can use that list of variables:

```
import pickle

with open('doc_name.txt','rb') as a:
     saved_variable_list = pickle.load(a)
```

Finally to close your GUI you can use the 'destroy' command:

```
root.destroy()
```